# How to use SecureRandom output in a byte array properly?

Tags: java, arrays, byte, aes, secure-random

I am trying generate a random key with SecureRandom, but I am facing issues when putting the output in a byte array. It doesn't recognize the output of the SecureRandom.

```
public static String byteToHex(byte[] hash) {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(hash.length * 2);
           for(byte b: hash) {
                sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
           }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
            byte a[] = new byte[16]; 
            r.nextBytes(a);
```

I hardcode the output in a byte array:

```
byte[] k = {ac,1d,71,c8,96,bd,f7,d5,03,38,bc,46,a2,b4,f1,a8};
```

The error I get is:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - a2 cannot be resolved to a variable
    - bd cannot be resolved to a variable
    - d5 cannot be resolved to a variable
    - b4 cannot be resolved to a variable
    - c8 cannot be resolved to a variable
    - f7 cannot be resolved to a variable
    - a8 cannot be resolved to a variable
    - f1 cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from double 
     to byte
    - ac cannot be resolved to a variable
    - bc cannot be resolved to a variable
    - Type mismatch: cannot convert from double 
     to byte
```

I want to use it as a key to encrypt a message with AES

Comment: `ac` is an identifier. `0xac` (or better `0xAC`) is a hexadecimal `int` literal. Correct way is: `byte[] k = { (byte)0xAC, (byte)0x1D, (byte)0x71, (byte)0xC8,` and so forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you have got from an earlier execution of your snippet has been formatted in a way which is not valid Java code.
It seems the numbers are written in hexadecimal notation.
To use that in Java you have to [prepend `0x`](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/Hexadecimalintegerliteral.htm) to the numbers. These will then be interpreted as integers, therefore you have to cast them to bytes (which works as your numbers are small enough):

```
byte[] = { (byte) 0xac, (byte) 0x1d, ... };
```

Comment: I am used to work with bytes in C, so I wasn't aware of that. Thanks!